# How to use index method to display a listing of the resource in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I created a `customerController` with Laravel resource. Now I want to show the list of the customers from the database using the `index()` method and it doesn't work when I visit the `customer/index` route. However if use the `show()` method instead and visit the `customer/show` route, it works perfectly.

Why does this behave this way and how do I get the `index()` method to do this?

```php
class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $customers = Customer::all();
        return view('customer')->with('customers' , $customers);
    }

   public function show($id)
    {
       // adding the code in the index() method here makes the code run
       // as expected
    }
}
```

**customer.blade.php**

```php
<ul>
    @foreach($customers as $customer)
        <li>{{$customer->name}}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

**routes/web.php**

```php
Route::resource('customer' , 'CustomerController');
```

I expect the output to be:

```php
.sucre
.hameed
.micheal
```

Comment: What do you get when you visit the `customer/index` route and how do you know that it doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't display the list i'm fetching from the database

Comment: `it doesn't work`, `It doesn't display the list` - what does happen?  What do you see?  Errors?  Some other content?  Explain your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just learned how to use resource on Laravel 8.
Which  version are you using?
Run `php artisan route:list` on your console to see every route available and their names.

To see all customers through your index function do the following:

```
public function index()
{
    $customers = Customer::all();
    return view('customer', [
        'customers' => $customers
    ]);
}
```

Now just access your `customer.blade.php` file on browser.

PS: Don't forget of `@foreach`

```
@foreach ($customers as $customer)
    {{ $customer->attribute }}
@endforeach
```

Hope this could be useful.